# El innerHTML sale null

Tags: javascript, html, json

buenas tardes estoy tratando de proyectar en un div un objeto que tengo en el localstorage pero cada vez que lo intento o me sale innerHTML null.

creí que podría ser que el div no tiene el id pero si, les agradecería si me pudieran ayudar

```js
 'use strict'
 
 //introducir valor
 
 localStorage.setItem("Paises", "Colombia");
 
 //Recuperar un valor
 document.querySelector("#NM").innerHTML= localStorage.getItem("Paises");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang=es>
  <head>
   <meta charset= "UTF-8"/>
   <title>JavaScrip</title>
   <script src="js/localstorage.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <p></p>
   </br></br></br>
   <div id="Mostrar">
   </div>
   <div id="NM"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: No se si te equivocaste haciendo tu pregunta o si realmente lo tienes así, pero al momento de capturar el valor guardado en el localStorage estas copiando localtorage ... osea te falta la S

Comment: Si fue error al copiar pero ya lo tengo con la S y me aparece lo mismo

Comment: Ese código funciona, https://jsfiddle.net/cstgm8ua/ quizá estas corriendo el js antes que el html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código es funcional, tu falló es por:

- Mandas llamar el JS que con tiene tu código antes de la creación del div donde colocaras el valor con `innerHTML`
- Mueve tu llamado al JS justo antes de la etiqueta de cierre del body, para que en dicho momento el div al que le asignarass valor ya exista en el DOM

Mira tú código funcionando

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=es>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>JavaScrip</title>
    <script src="js/localstorage.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p></p>
    </br></br></br>
    <div id="Mostrar">
    </div>
    <div id="NM"></div>
    <script>
      'use strict'

      //introducir valor    
      localStorage.setItem("Paises", "Colombia");

      //Recuperar un valor
      document.querySelector("#NM").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Paises");

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Emeeus gracias por la edición, pues desde el móvil es complejo